# How to create this abstract animation in Blender?

Tags: animation, modifiers, keyframes, animation-nodes, shape-keys

How to create this abstract animation in Blender?
I don't know how to make the object rotate in this way? I tried to add Shape Keys, but doesn't work.
[image]

Here is my blender file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zFrizwPYCivnB3DxJNT5JXVwCduLBYca/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I would say Geometry Nodes, but I hardly know anything about them. Maybe try a cyclic curve with animated twist?

Comment: Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.